# Crop confirm jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to create croping system php and jquery . I did some research and learned a few things. But i have a problem at the moment. In the following code have confirm. I do not want to encounter such a warning. The system works like this: When you apply the process to select the desired area of the image against the following warning turns out to (( Do you want to save image..! ))But I do not want such a warning. Can you help me on this issue.
http://goo.gl/zXhvGG

```
function getSizes(im, obj) {
    var x_axis = obj.x1;
    var x2_axis = obj.x2;
    var y_axis = obj.y1;
    var y2_axis = obj.y2;
    var thumb_width = obj.width;
    var thumb_height = obj.height;
    if (thumb_width > 0) {
        if (confirm("Do you want to save image..!")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ajax_image.php?t=ajax&img=" + $("#image_name").val() + "&w=" +
                    thumb_width + "&h=" + thumb_height + "&x1=" + x_axis + "&y1=" + y_axis,
                cache: false,
                success: function (rsponse) {
                    $("#cropimage").hide();
                    $("#thumbs").html("");
                    $("#thumbs").html("<img src='uploads/" + rsponse + "' />");
                }
            });
        }
    } else
        alert("Please select portion..!");
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img#photo').imgAreaSelect({
        aspectRatio: '1:1',
        onSelectEnd: getSizes
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
            $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

            if(strlen($name))
                {
                    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats) && $size<(1024*1024))
                        {
                            $actual_image_name = time().substr($txt, 5).".".$ext;
                            $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                                {
                                mysql_query("UPDATE users SET profile_image='$actual_image_name' WHERE uid='$session_id'");
                                    $image="<h1>Please drag on the image</h1><img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."' id=\"photo\" style='max-width:500px' >";

                                }
                            else
                                echo "failed";
                        }
                    else
                        echo "Invalid file formats..!";                 
                }
            else
                echo "Please select image..!";
        }
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="margin:0 auto; width:600px">
<?php echo $image; ?>
<div id="thumbs" style="padding:5px; width:600px"></div>
<div style="width:600px">

<form id="cropimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload your image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
    <input type="hidden" name="image_name" id="image_name" value="<?php echo($actual_image_name)?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</div>
</div>
```

**Ajax.php**

```
<?php
include('db.php');
session_start();
$session_id='1'; // Session_id
$t_width = 100; // Maximum thumbnail width
$t_height = 100;    // Maximum thumbnail height
$new_name = "small".$session_id.".jpg"; // Thumbnail image name
$path = "uploads/";
if(isset($_GET['t']) and $_GET['t'] == "ajax")
    {
        extract($_GET);
        $ratio = ($t_width/$w); 
        $nw = ceil($w * $ratio);
        $nh = ceil($h * $ratio);
        $nimg = imagecreatetruecolor($nw,$nh);
        $im_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($path.$img);
        imagecopyresampled($nimg,$im_src,0,0,$x1,$y1,$nw,$nh,$w,$h);
        imagejpeg($nimg,$path.$new_name,90);
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET profile_image_small='$new_name' WHERE uid='$session_id'");
        echo $new_name."?".time();
        exit;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Why not simply swap out the `confirm(..)` with `1` or `true` so you don't have to worry about modifying the `if` block?

Comment: why don't you just remove the confirm condition?

Comment: @uchamp thanks for reply can you check my question in this link http://goo.gl/zXhvGG

Comment: @MustafaOzturk your link does not contain a button to save the cropped image?

Comment: @Bellash yes dear you are right i learn it now. How can i add save the cropped image button?!

Comment: you need to send it by post! your ajax must be post method... I am editing my answer to help you

Comment: @Bellash thank you i added my ajax code in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the confirm from your js code. So, use this code instead

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function getSizes(im, obj) {
        var x_axis = obj.x1;
        var x2_axis = obj.x2;
        var y_axis = obj.y1;
        var y2_axis = obj.y2;
        var thumb_width = obj.width;
        var thumb_height = obj.height;
        if (thumb_width > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ajax_image.php?t=ajax&img=" + $("#image_name").val() + "&w=" + thumb_width + "&h=" + thumb_height + "&x1=" + x_axis + "&y1=" + y_axis,
                cache: false,
                success: function (rsponse) {
                    $("#cropimage").hide();
                    $("#thumbs").html("");
                    $("#thumbs").html("<img src='uploads/" + rsponse + "' />");
                }
            });
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('img#photo').imgAreaSelect({
            aspectRatio: '1:1',
            onSelectEnd: getSizes
        });
    });
      </script>
```

Comment: this code is right thank you. But How can I add the Save button in the Crop Can you help me?